# How to mixing an array values in order?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to mix arrays values to display in order:

```
$array_one = array('a','b','c');
$array_two = array('1','2','3','4','5');
```

The result should be:

```
array('a','1','b','2','c','3','4','5');
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you tried anything? please post it

Comment: What kind of order is that? You first need to be able to define this *order* before you can apply it

Comment: i'm trying "count" arrays, "for" loop and than array_splice, but not successful yet.

Comment: post your trial, then we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you what you want

```
$array_one = array('a','b','c');
$array_two = array('1','2','3','4','5');
$maxCount = max(array(count($array_one),count($array_two)));

$result = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $maxCount; $i++) {
  if (!empty($array_one[$i])) {
    $result[] = $array_one[$i];
  }
  if (!empty($array_two[$i])) {
    $result[] = $array_two[$i];
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

Comment: @Andrei: consider upvoting and accepting so people know it's solved

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays have the same number of elements you could use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create what you want.

```
$array_one = array('a','b','c','d','e');
$array_two = array('1','2','3','4','5');

$combined_array = array_combine($array_one, $array_two);
array_walk($combined_array, create_function('$value, $key', 'echo "$key $value ";'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi @andrei you first find the length of both arrays, create a new array for the result,use two for loops in the inner loop just assign the values in new array and increment the loops. hope it give you expected result.